# Is this sentence grammatically right?

Tags: grammaticality

> Thanks for asking for answering.

If not, then what is the correct form and why?
I am confused with "for".

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @snailplane I guess, given the "for",  the sentence is "Thanks for asking for answering."

Comment: Are you saying thanks to a person who asked for answering?

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, but I can't tell what that sentence is meant to express, so I was hoping the OP could clarify a little.

Comment: In Quora app, most of the people write this

Comment: Either "Thanks for asking." or "Thanks for answering." should be fine, but I can't tell if I'm missing any additional context that would warrant needing both.

Comment: @user55697, can you paraphrase what you meant by this sentence using another one? It's very hard to figure out what you intended. (Alexander's options make sense but it's not clear what you wanted to say.)

Comment: @user55697 Please **edit the question** to state _where_ you hear/want to say this, _the situation/context_ where it is said and also paraphrase what you want it to say/what it should say using more words/other sentences.

Comment: Is this **one** phrase or are you saying "Thanks for asking/answering"? - Essentially, there are two very common phrases - "Thanks for asking" and "Thanks for answering". Both of these are fine but I've never seen anyone combine the two into a single phrase.

Comment: @Catija Phrases like those aren't combined the way the OP has written it because it isn't grammatical to use "for" twice like that. The way you wrote it isn't proper but is otherwise fine for text.

Comment: @Alexander This is why we need context from the OP. Native speakers are _constantly_ calling sentences ungrammatical that are actually fine in context, because the sentence by itself doesn't suggest the context and people seldom appreciate the role of context in grammar. In this case, imagine that you ran an answering service, and you were glad that someone inquired about hiring you. Or who knows what the situation might be?

Answer (score 0):

They write it *wrong!*

Quora has a feature called A2A i.e. 'Ask to Answer'. Here, if you have Quora Credits, you can 'ask' directly to someone who has an expertise on the subject for what you have asked the question.

Say, if you ask something on 'health', you probably want a doctor to answer. Now, if you have certain credit, you can ask a doctor there. [Learn here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Ask-to-Answer-and-how-does-it-work) how Quora A2A works.

Now, when *that* doctor gets a message that someone *specifically asked him*, he would certainly *thank* the asker first. That said, it can be thanked in two ways:

> Thanks for *asking to answer* the question **OR** 
>  Thanks for 'Ask to Answer'

Note that the second option has inverted commas stating that those words are actually a 'label' or 'title.'

Comment: Thanks for the context. I'll add that the "inverted commas" are **single quotation marks**. They function the same as regular (double) quotation marks but are unconventional to use outside of using a quote inside of a quote.

Comment: @Alexander In British English, single quotes are more conventional as the outer quotation marks, and both single and double are called "inverted commas". A little more is here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/inverted-commas-quotation-marks